# Find the Kernel distribution over an already known histogram

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, histograms

I have an estimated distribution over a parameter, however, the distribution is not continuous, and  `InterpolatingPolynomial` cannot estimate my distribution good enough, so I am going to use the Kernel distribution.

I have seen `SmoothKernelDistribution` function, but that applies only on a data. I already have a histogram, how can I find its kernel separately?

Lets say these are my histogram x and y axis :

```
positin of columns={0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5}
height= {0.000123464, 0.0086719, 0.119523, 0.394129, 0.36659, 0.105748, 0.00521382}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
positionofcolumns = {0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5};
height = {0.000123464, 0.0086719, 0.119523, 0.394129, 0.36659, 0.105748, 0.00521382};
```

You can use [`WeightedData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeightedData.html) with `height` as the weight vector:

```
wd = WeightedData[positionofcolumns, height]

SmoothHistogram[wd]
```

[image]

```
skd = SmoothKernelDistribution[wd]

Plot[PDF[skd, x], {x, 0,.8}]
```

[image]

Comment: Great, and how do you make it normalized?! sorry, it's a basic question I know.

Comment: The integral over the finalized probability  should be 1. In the final graph it's reaching  8. My original data points reach 0.34 .

Comment: @aaa, `PDF[skd,x]` does integrate to `1`: try  `NIntegrate[PDF[skd, x], {x,0, 1}]`. Btw, values in `height` are not directly comparable to the height of the continuous PDF; you should get something comparable to the height of a bin if you integrate the pdf between the relevant bin limits.

Comment: ok this is weird, I tried that and I'm getting something close to 1. If PDF is giving a probability of distribution then how can it be larger than 1 at some values?

Comment: @aaa, I get `1.` when I run `Integrate[PDF[skd, x], {x,0, 1}] ` and  `Integrate[PDF[skd, x], {x,-Infinity, Infinity}]`  (v12 on Wolfram Cloud)

Comment: yea, I did that too, and I  get one, I remembered that PDF is different from probability, can you tell me how can I find the probability from PDF, the probability should be below 1 at all points.

Comment: @aaa, for a continuous  random variable _probability_ makes sense only for intervals. For the case `positionofcolumns` are centers of equally spaced bins, you can use `CDF[skd,#]&/@Append[positionofcolumns-.05,Last[positionofcolumns]+.05] // Differences` to get probabilities of bins.

Comment: The height of each bin is already its probability, I don't get what do you mean.

Comment: @aaa, I was responding to "how can I find the probability from PDF".

Comment: `Total@{Probability[x < 0.225, x \[Distributed] skd],
  Probability[0.225 < x < 0.275, x \[Distributed] skd],
  Probability[0.275 < x < 0.325, x \[Distributed] skd],
  Probability[0.325 < x < 0.375, x \[Distributed] skd],
  Probability[0.375 < x < 0.425, x \[Distributed] skd],
  Probability[0.425 < x < 0.475, x \[Distributed] skd],
  Probability[x > 0.475, x \[Distributed] skd]}` evaluates to `1.`